# find all div's with contenteditable attribute in iframe and remove said attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ifram on a page with class ms-dlgFrame and in this iframe I want to remove contenteditable="true" on elements since it's not supported by Safari on iPad (I am checking the user agent first).

I have some issues with combining `.find(), .each(), .attr()`, and `.removeAttr()`

I tried something like:

```
console.log("iPad");
$('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find("div").attr("contenteditable").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable");

});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the selector `div[contenteditable='true']` and drop the `attr()` call from your chain:

```
console.log("iPad");
$('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find("div[contenteditable='true']").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable");
});
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `div[contenteditable="true"]`? it could be that the quotes don't make a difference. my apologies if that's the case.

Comment: @AndyL Yes, you're correct it that should be quoted. Edited, thanks.